# Separate array of one string connected with a plus sign to array of multiple strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array which only includes one entry, which are strings separated by a plus sign, as below:

```
['string one' + 'string two' + 'string three']
```

I want to make it so that each string is separated by a comma, as so:

```
['string one', 'string two', 'string three']
```

I've been trying to use split or join, but that hasn't worked yet. I'm writing it as a node script.

Comment: Use `split` with `' + '` as the delimiter.

Comment: Please show your attempts; you may be close to a solution.

Comment: What you've written for the input isn't valid for the description "an array which only includes one entry, which are strings separated by a plus sign" - perhaps the outer single quotes `'` should be double quotes `"`?

Comment: @Klaycon fixed - thanks for flagging.

Comment: Your edited input is equivalent to `['string onestring twostring three']` There are no plus signs in the strings.

Comment: @Barmar the plus signs are in between the strings, I essentially want to replace them with commas.

Comment: Plus signs between strings perform concatenation. There's no way to tell where the original strings were.

Comment: @LukeByrne How are you receiving this input? Is it just in your code? Why not replace the plus signs with commas manually in your code, using a find/replace..?

Comment: @Klaycon it's coming from an API unfortunately so need to transform it!

Comment: Please show what `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable))` looks like.

Comment: @LukeByrne, so you're receiving *a string* from a REST call which looks like this: `"['string one' + 'string two' + 'string three']"` - is that right?

Comment: No I'm receiving an array - it's structured as above, no quotes around the array

Comment: @LukeByrne It's not possible for you to receive an array with plusses between the strings. String concatenation can only exist in code, not as an HTTP response. Try what Barmar suggested.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) plus withholding essential information.

Comment: @LukeByrne Understand that what you are showing is not something an API could provide to you. It is logically impossible.

Comment: @Klaycon I'll take a look at my code now and post the code I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice()` to remove the first and last quotes from the string. Then use `split()` with `' + '` as the delimiter.

```js
var input = ["'string one' + 'string two' + 'string three'"];
var str = input[0];
var output = str.slice(1, -2).split("' + '");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, I had an error in my original question, I fixed it but still have the same problem.

Comment: Your edit got rid of the plus signs in the input string.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm working with - I'm getting the info from an API and that's how it's structured. I want to essentially replace the plus signs with commas.

Comment: You don't seem to be describing it well. What you've written is not valid syntax for an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can  `split` according to the character and remove the surrounding apostrophes:

```js
let arr = ["'string one' + 'string two' + 'string three'"];
let list = arr[0].split('+').map(str=>{
     return str.trim().replace(/'/g,"");
});
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and split

```
var items = ["'string one' + 'string two' + 'string three'"];
items.map(function(item) { 
return item.split('+');
});
```

Comment: This will return a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: It also doesn't remove the nested quotes.